# Adjusting for color difference between monitor and TV

Tags: color, color-perception

I am creating a UI, but there is a large difference between the colors that I can see on my monitor, and my TV.

Is there a way to adjust for the difference between what I see on my monitor and my TV?

As an extreme case, let us assume that my monitor displays 000000 (black), and my TV displays 666666 (gray). I got this value for my TV by checking it via color picker (or some other software, perhaps?)

So to remove the difference, I would simply deduct the difference (666666) from the color value of the TV.

Now, let us say I pick another color, say, aaddff, on my TV, I subtract 666666 from it, it becomes 447799.

Am I in the right direction?

Is there an app or software that can help me with finding out the DISPLAYED color on a monitor/screen?

Comment: Hi Fraglord, welcome to the board! Is your UI something that will be viewed on a tv? or what is the UI for?

Comment: the UI is meant to be used on TVs. i have a few unknown colors on screen. i want to figure out which colors they are, so i can track them down in the code. FE, 0x303030 on my monitor displays like 0x434236 on TV. its not EXACTLY that color, since I had to eyeball it. i'm only looking for approximate situations.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. One glaring reason is, what if the color is #006600. How would you subtract #666666 from that when you can't use negative numbers? But that's one of the reasons the method won't work.

There is a rolloff, a curve, in the display of colors. Each color is controlled independently. Some TVs are better at consistency than others, thus all the reviews you'll find online. Analog TVs are worse than digital. You might Google for "gamme".

So there is a lot more involved than just subtracting a base value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard colour settings for TV's, and many people adjust them to suit their personal preferences. There are so many settings available, which can make large adjustments to what is displayed, that you're not going to be able to find a definitive answer.

E.g. your #666666 offset could be easily changed by altering the contrast or brightness settings a few clicks either way. Once you start getting into colour saturation, tone or gamma settings then you've got no chance of finding any sort of fixed offset. And even if you did get it for one display, the next one is going to have a different offset.

These differences pose real issues for games, especially things like first person shooters where they need to be able to have things almost, but not quite, in darkness. To allow for a range of screens and their set ups, many allow you to adjust the gamma settings of the game.

Here's a video showing the way brightness can be adjusted in Doom

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEGjTHl_7KI] -